# How to have onCreateOptionsMenu items only appear in one toolbar and not both?

Tags: android, menu, action, toolbar, items

I have two Android Material Design toolbars on my app, similarly to Instagram.  I want to add menu items to my top toolbar but they show up on my bottom toolbar as well.  Any ideas on how I can have an onCreateOptionsMenu function that only adds menu items to one toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `menuInflater` to inflate the menu, you should just use the `ActionBar` to inflate the menu like so:

```
mActionBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_menu);
```

As opposed to this

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
```

Comment: Well, this should work.  It doesn't unfortunately.  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Just to clarify, the onCreateOptionsMenu is working (but still inflates the menu on both actionbars).  Yeah, not sure why my inflateMenu isn't.

Comment: Ohh didn't see your response until now.  Calling .inflateMenu on my toptoolbar isn't inflating the menu.  Not giving an error either

Comment: Are you using it as a stand alone widget or as a replacement for your ActionBar?

Comment: replacement for ActionBar as well as a standalone widget on the bottom, similarly to Instagram

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant code along with the onCreateOptionsMenu method?

Answer (score 0):

> Add the code of main activity :

```
ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
              Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
              if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
              }
```